# how to solve the invalid left-hand side assignment?

Tags: javascript, function, buzz.js

i have a function in which there is a error coming in a inspect element it is uncaughtReferenceError:Invalid left-hand side assignment & i'm using buzz.js library for sound so the function is:

```
function clickedbar(e)
{
  var mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
  var newtime=mouseX*mysound.getDuration()/240;
  mysound.getTime()=newtime;
  progressbar.style.width=mouseX+'px';
}
```

I'm getting error in the 3rd line of that function that is "mysound.getTime()=newtime".How i can solve this line of code,all other lines are working fine,please someone help me out of this.

Comment: `newtime=mysound.getTime()`

Comment: You cannot do: mysound.getTime() = newtime; since mysound.getTime() is a getter not a setter, so you can't set a value to a function like that. Show us where mysound is declared (at least), so you can have a proper answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Buzz.js library has a setter for this, so instead of:

```
mysound.getTime() = newtime;
```

do:

```
mysound.setTime(newtime);
```

Based on it's documentation: http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/sound/

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value to a function call

```
mysound.getTime()=newtime;
```

if it is a property then do this

```
mysound.getTime=newtime;
```

or is there a setTime method?

Comment: i get that thing but i want that the current time of my sound should be equal to the variable newtime.